# How does name lookup work in Powershell script blocks?

Tags: class, powershell

User cashfoley has posted what appears to be a fairly elegant set of code at [codeplex](http://psclass.codeplex.com/) for a "module" called PSClass.

When I dot-source the psclass code into some code of my own, I am able to write code like:

```
$Animal = New-PSClass Animal {

    constructor {
        param( $name, $legs )

        # ...
    }

    method -override ToString {
        "A $($this.Class.ClassName) named $($this.name) with $($this.Legs) Legs"
    }
}
```

When I tried to create a module out of the PSClass code, however, I started getting errors. The `constructor` and `method` names are no longer recognized.

Looking at the actual implementation, what I see is that `constructor`, `method`, etc. are actually nested functions inside the New-PSClass function.

Thus, it seems to me that when I dot-source the PSClass.ps1 file, my script-blocks are allowed to contain references to functions nested inside other local functions. But when the PSClass code becomes a module, with the New-PSClass function exported (I tried both using a manifest and using Export-ModuleMember), the names are no longer visible.

Can someone explain to me how the script blocks, scoping rules, and visibility rules for nested functions work together?

Also, kind of separately, is there a better class definition protocol for pure Powershell scripting? (Specifically, one that does not involve "just write it in C# and then do this...")

Comment: ps> get-help about_scopes | more

Answer (score 0):

The variables in your script blocks don't get evaluated until they are executed.  If the variables in the script block don't exist in the current scope when the block is executed, the variables won't have any values.  Script blocks aren't closures: they don't capture the context at instantiation time.

```
Remove-variable FooBar

function New-ScriptBlock
{
    $FooBar = 1

    $scriptBlock = {
        Write-Host "FooBar: $FooBar"
    }

    $FooBar = 2
    & $scriptBlock  # Outputs FooBar: 2 because $FooBar was set to 2 before invocation
    return $scriptBlock
}

function Invoke-ScriptBlock
{
    param(
        $ScriptBlock
    )

    & $ScriptBlock
}

$scriptBlock = New-ScriptBlock 

& $scriptBlock    # Prints nothing since $FooBar doesn't exist in this scope

$FooBar = 3
Invoke-ScriptBlock $scriptBlock   # Prints $FooBar: 3 since FooBar set to 3
```

Comment: IF this is true, then why does putting the outer function in a module not work?